# TextBox Only Accepts Numeric and Comma- C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

I want to restrict textbox which should only accepts numbers and comma.How can i do this keypress ??

Example:

```
 1,2,223,222 -->Valid
 1,,22,,33   -->Invalid
 ab,c,d      -->Invalid
```

Comment: Read about [MaskedTextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: If you want to *validate* input, the pattern can be `"^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*$"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to *validate* input, you can use *regular expression*:

```
  String input = "1,2,223,222";
  String pattern = "^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*$";

  Console.Write(Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern) ? "valid" : "invalid");
```

Little test:

```
   String[] tests = new String[] {
     "1,2,223,222",
     "1,,22,,33",
     "ab,c,d", 
   };

   var report = tests
     .Select(item => String.Format("{0,-12} --> {1}", 
                                   item, 
                                   Regex.IsMatch(item, pattern) ? "valid" : "invalid"));

   // 1,2,223,222  --> valid
   // 1,,22,,33    --> invalid
   // ab,c,d       --> invalid
   Console.Write(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, report));
```

In case you want to *restrict* input, please, *think twice*: what is the right procedure for user to input, say

```
  1,2
```

with input restriction it can't be *natural* and *self-evident* one

```
  "1" -> "1," (invalid! System prevents such an input) -> "1,2"
```

but *strange*

```
  "1" -> "12" -> "1,2"
```

So I suggest *lenient* user input control:

```
private void myControl_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
  // temporary invalid inputs like "1," are allowed
  if ((e.KeyChar < 32) || (e.KeyChar >= '0') && (e.KeyChar <= '9') || (e.KeyChar == ','))
    return;

  // only evident errors (like 'A' or '&') are restricted
  e.Handled = true;
}
```

and then, finally, (on `OK` click etc.) validate.

Comment: Dmitry Bychenko .. Only problem with this solution is it will not handle consequent commas (eg ; 1,,2)

Comment: @vmb: the question states that *consequent commas* are *invalid*: `1,,22,,33   -->Invalid` (the 2nd example from the question). If these inputs are valid in fact, please edit the question.

Comment: @vmb: In case you allow consequent commas *within* the input like `1,,,2`, but not accept *dangling* ones (e.g. `,1` or `2,`) then the pattern can be `"^[0-9]|([0-9](,|[0-9])*[0-9])$"`

Comment: Yes..I want o restrict consequent commas(ie.u ser should not able to enter second comma

Comment: @vmb: if you plan to add restriction in the `KeyPress`, please, *think twice* again: what if user wants to add the first item, then the last one: `15,,25` and then compute and insert, say, the *average* in the middle: `15,20,25`? A better policy is to restrict just *evident errors* (e.g. `A` or `-`) and not interfere user to input the right string in the way he/she wants.